# Regex : find values separate with coma between tag

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Il would like find all values between tag (`[...]`) separate by coma `,`.

Example :

```
text ['value1',5,6] text
```

Result : `$1 = 'value1'`, `$2 = 5`, `$3 = 6`

```
text text text ['value2',1] text
```

Result : `$1 = 'value2'`, `$2 = 1`

Do you have an idea ?
Thanks

I tried with `\[(.+)\]` and i tried other methods but I can't get the desired result.

Comment: Use `\[(.*?)\]` and then split with a comma, or use a common regex matching between quotes (with an alternative for digits). Like `/'((?:[^'\\]|\\.)*)'|\d+/g`. It can be further enhanced to meet your needs. If you still have issues, please update the question with your current code and test case explaining what still does not work.

Comment: Is it possible have something like this as input: `Text ['another [1,23,4] text',4,        3] another text ['1,2']`?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/y3Icie/3

Comment: No need to try, my https://regex101.com/r/y3Icie/4 - based on the linked answers - works well enough.